# Slush's pool worker offline

Tags: mining-pools, guiminer

I'm new to mining, and using GUI miner on windows 7 AMD APU A-Series. I set it up today, put in my username.workername and put in stratum.bitcoin.cz as the host, and 3333 as the port. It says I'm getting 2 MHash/sec, but when I go to the Slush's pool website it says my worker is offline!

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: shows me offline too. I have an MSI GT70 Intel i7 2.4ghz. It is showing that i am offline, but i am getting about 25-28 MH/s... Don't know...

Comment: 25-28 MH/s is essentially the same as zero. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

At this point 2 TH/s is ok for small miners, 2 GH/s is crazy slow and 2 MH/s is probably not enough for the pool to even detect that you are mining at all. So that's most likely your problem.

Even the best gaming computers had to give up in 2013. Mining is now done on ASIC hardware. Computers are just too slow.